Possible typo in "Introduction to set theory" third edition by T. Jech
In the chapter 8, section 1, page 143 of the book "Introduction to set theory" third edition by T. Jech appears .
The issue I have is that I don't understand why it says $\xi \in A$ in the highlighted parts of the image. I think it should be $\xi \in \lambda$ or $a_{\xi} \in A$, but I'm not really sure if I'm wrong and I don't really understand the proof, or if it is a typo.

It's a typo.  It should be $a_{\xi} \in A$.

$\xi\in\lambda\iff a_{\xi}\in A$ by definition of the sequence, so you can pick either one.
